# passing vs having passed

Tags: tense, verbs

After ***_*__*_*__** MA Economics he joined the London School of Economics.

I am confused about using "passing" or "having passed"?

*Edit - I did some research and from what I gathered, the answer is "passing" because using "having passed" with "after" will bring a sense of redundancy. The "having passed" form of the verb has the "after" inherent in it.

Answer (score 6):

In your test the correct answer is, probably, *passing*. That's what *Murphy's English Grammar* says:

> When one action happens before another action, we use **having
> (done)** for the first action:
>
> > **Having finished** her work, she went home.
>
> You can also say **after -ing**:
>
> > **After finishing** her work, she went home.

So, when there is the word *after*, it is more "right" to use **[verb]-ing**. But note that **after having (done)** occurs in practical usage. These sentences I've found on *Google News*:

> *After having done* this, he returned to the scene
>
> A bus driver almost choked to death *after having found* a coil in his two chicken breasts
>
> Khan thought he had the fight with Mayweather wrapped up *after having won* a poll on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Passing is the correct answer. Having past is the present perfect form meaning that the event is still going on; whereas here, he first passed MA Economics and then joined that particular school.

Comment: Since when do we call HAVE + verb+ED present continuous? Looks like a perfective form to me. (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle You're right. I meant to say present perfect.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. I've read a bit just now and found out that the first part of the sentence looks like a "participial phrase". Not sure what the tense of that may be and whether it has a tense as such. Seems to be a 'participial clause using past participle':
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_clause

Answer (score 0):

To me, the meaning of `after finishing` and `after having finished` is very close. I would say the latter adds the connotation that finishing MA Economics is a long process. I would also say that the latter is less common in colloquial conversations.

After comparing some of the occurrences linked by [Google's n-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=after+finishing%2Cafter+having+finished%2C+after+completing%2Cafter+having+completed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cafter%20finishing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20having%20finished%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20completing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20having%20completed%3B%2Cc0), I see both cases used in similar contexts:

- "he left the country after having completed his education"
- "after completing his education he settled in his native town"

There is, though, a clear trend to use the shorter and simpler version `after finishing`.

[image: Imgur]